# GetSelectLink grows longer and longer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm trying to use a WebGrid on a ASP.NET MVC 4 website. Each row contains a link at the end that is created by

```
@item.GetSelectLink("Select")
```

Selection works like a charm. However there is an issue I'd like to address as I can't figure out what it's caused by. The link generated by GetSelectLink is getting a parameter named _swhg which is set to a supposedly random number (looks like some sort of a timestamp, doesn't really matter anyway). Everytime I click on "Select" this parameter gets another number appended. So after clicking on "Select" several times the link looks like that:

```
http://localhost:59215/Buecher?Auswahl=1&__swhg=1347207774869,1347207775030,1347207775221,1347207775380,1347207775548
```

Due to that clicking on "Select" some more eventually ends up in a 404 as soon as the url grows too long.

Has anybody got an idea what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: What is the `GetSelectLink` method? Could you show it?

Comment: It is used to create a link that sets the SelectedRow property of the WebGrid control. See it in line 24 at http://pastebin.com/tvi22CTV and in the MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridrow.getselectlink%28v=vs.111%29.aspx